# Finding two points B and C such that the perimeter of triangle ABC is minimal

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Given an acute angle XOY and an interior point A. Find a point B on the side OX and a point C on the side OY such that the perimeter of the triangle ABC is minimal.
>   Hint: Introduce points symmetric to A with respect to the sides of the angle.

I found this problem in Kiselev's Geometry: Planimetry. I do not know what a minimum perimeter looks like or how it appears in algebraic form.

Comment: AB=AC and angle sum OBA+ OCA minimum ... only a guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

That is a variation of some very common questions about minimal distance.

Take $A_x$ symmetric of $A$ w.r.t $OX$ and $A_y$ symmetric of $A$ w.r.t $OY$.

Now take the line $A_xA_y$ and see that $A_xB=AB$ (because $A_x$ symmetric of $A$) and $A_yC=AC$.

Once $A_xA_y$ is the minimal distante from $A_x$ to $A_y$ then $$AB+BC+AC=A_xB+BC+A_yC=A_xA_y$$ is also minimal.

Comment: Don't you mean that AyC = AC?

Comment: And how do I know that AxAy is the minimal distance from Ax to Ay?

Comment: @Omicron: You are right about the first comment. I updated the answer. About the second, $A_xA_y$ is a straight line, so it is the minimal distance.

Comment: I can choose B to have a straight line with Ax and choose C to have a straight line with Ay. But I cannot prove that BC is the continuation of AxB and AyB. Hence, I cannot prove that AxAy is a straight line. Tell me what's wrong with this argument.

Comment: The idea is construct points $A_x$ and $A_y$ and take the straight line $A_xA_y$. $B$ and $C$ will be the intersection with $OX$ and $OY$.

Comment: Of course! Sorry for my dumb questions. I just need to ask them to really understand the problem. Thanks man.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$B$ and $C$ have to be such that $AB$ and $AC$  are the minimal distances from $A$ to the sides of the angle. This means that they are orthogonal to the sides.

Comment: Why must $B,C$ have minimal distance to the rays?