# Finding two points B and C such that the perimeter of triangle ABC is minimal (an extension)

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

I was going to ask this question but the problem has been posted here: [Finding two points B and C such that the perimeter of triangle ABC is minimal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208568/finding-two-points-b-and-c-such-that-the-perimeter-of-triangle-abc-is-minimal) . I tried to confirm the solution using the software and it does confirm that the triangle has the smallest perimeter. However, it feels like the answer(the proof) is incomplete. Consider the figure I generated below.

[image]

I simply choose a random points A,B on $OX$ and $OY$, and constructed the triangle. Then, I added the circles to generate the segment along the line $BC$.

I have satisfied the condition : $$AB+BC+AC=A_xB+BC+A_yC=A_xA_y$$
By simply leaving the argument at that then I also have a triangle whose perimeter is minimum. However, it is not. What makes the triangle Arnaldo made to be the correct triangle.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment / request for clarification at the linked post, not as a different question. Arnaldo's solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: Then by his argument, my triangle is also a minimum.

Comment: Why? I do not get it. Arnaldo's solution also shows the solution is unique (hence the only solution is his solution) because the shortest path between to fixed points in the plane is unique, and it is the segment joining them.

Comment: If you choose two random points on $OX$ and $OY$ you do not get four collinear points as needed by minimality.

Comment: Your $A_x, A_y$ do not have a fixed distance, that is the whole point.

Comment: This belongs in a comment/question below Arnaldo question.